# How to remove overlapping rectangles (C#, System.Drawing) while keeping only the one with a certain attribute?

Tags: c#, algorithm, system.drawing

For a class that stores template matching results, I need to implement a efficent way of removing overlapping results (= overlapping bounding boxes, for e.g. this happens for low accuracy thresholds on template matching).

My Results variable in the example below is a dict<string, TemplateMatchingResult>, where the key is the name of the template and the value is aTemplateMatchingResult, which stores BoundingBoxes (actually List) and Scores (a List with the accuracy scores belonging to BoundingBoxes ).

In the first approach, I just compared them all by all and then removed the ones with lower score. But I often got IndexOutOfBoundsException for i2 here: `this.Results[key2].Scores.RemoveAt(i2)`

My second approach was to first store the indexes in a list (every index only once) belonging to the template name (used a dict for this: dict<string, List> ToDelete) and then remove them from outside of the loops and repeat this as long as it doesn't find any overlappings any more. But this also seems not very good, because the result still shows overlappings.

What would be the most efficient way to do this (Time Efficiency) ?

Here is my code for the removing:

```
public void RemoveOverlappingElements() 
        {
            // Check dictionary for null or empty
            if (this.Results != null && this.Results.Count != 0)
            {
                bool loopFlag = true;
                while(loopFlag)
                { 
                    Dictionary<string, List<int>> toDelete = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

                    //Search for overlapping bounding boxes
                    foreach (string key1 in this.Results.Keys)
                    {
                        // Use a second loop variable for comparison to the first one
                        foreach (string key2 in this.Results.Keys)
                        {
                            // Only compare elements that are not the same
                            if (key1 != key2)
                            {
                                // Compare every bounding box of the element corresponding to key1 to every bonding box of the element corresponding to key1
                                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < this.Results[key1].BoundingBoxes.Count; i1++)
                                {
                                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < this.Results[key2].BoundingBoxes.Count; i2++)
                                    {
                                        //Check if they overlap, and store key and index for elements with the lowest accuracy score
                                        if (this.Results[key1].BoundingBoxes[i1].GetRectangle().IntersectsWith(this.Results[key2].BoundingBoxes[i2].GetRectangle()))
                                        {
                                            if (this.Results[key1].Scores[i1] >= this.Results[key2].Scores[i2])
                                            {
                                                // Old Approach
                                                //this.Results[key2].Scores.RemoveAt(i2);
                                                //this.Results[key2].BoundingBoxes.RemoveAt(i2);

                                                // New approach
                                                // Only add keys that don't exist already and keep every index without duplicates
                                                if (toDelete.Keys.Contains(key2))
                                                {
                                                    toDelete[key2] = toDelete[key2].Union(new List<int> { i2 }).ToList();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    toDelete.Add(key2, new List<int> { i2 });
                                                }

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //this.Results[key1].Scores.RemoveAt(i1);
                                                //this.Results[key1].BoundingBoxes.RemoveAt(i1);

                                                // Only add keys that don't exist already and keep every index without duplicates
                                                if (toDelete.Keys.Contains(key1))
                                                {
                                                    toDelete[key1] = toDelete[key1].Union(new List<int> { i1 }).ToList();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    toDelete.Add(key1, new List<int> { i1 });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Delete bounding boxes and scores for the overlapping elements
                    if (toDelete.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in toDelete)
                        {
                            this.Results[item.Key].BoundingBoxes.RemoveAll(x => item.Value.Contains(this.Results[item.Key].BoundingBoxes.IndexOf(x)));
                            this.Results[item.Key].Scores.RemoveAll(x => item.Value.Contains(this.Results[item.Key].Scores.IndexOf(x)));
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        loopFlag = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient algorithm to solve your problem:

Create an undirected graph in which the vertices are rectangles and there is an edge between two vertices if the corresponding rectangles intersect.

Find all connected components in your graph (with a depth-first search, for example).

Select the rectangle with maximum score from each connected component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I guess I didn't explained the problem enough clearly in the first attempt.

Actualy, the problem is: I need to keep all the rectangles that have no intersection with others PLUS, from a bunch of rectangles that intersect, I need to keep only the one with the highest score and remove the others.

So for e.g.: Let's say we have 5 rectangles with only this relations:
R1 (80%) with no intersection,
R2 (30%) intersects R3 (40%),
R3  intersects R4 (50%),
R4 intersects R5 (45%)

As a result, I would need to keep only: R1 and R4 (and remove R2,R3,R5)

Comment: @EduardSzilaghi I updated my answer according to the problem you described.